# Destroy action is not working in rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller

```
def destroy 
  @idea = Idea.find(params[:id]) 
  @idea.destroy 
  flash[:success] = "The idea was successfully deleted!" 
  redirect_to root_path 
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', idea_path(idea), :method => :delete, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

Why it is not working? It throws some errors like:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in IdeasController#destroy

def handle_unverified_request
  raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
end
```

Comment: Did you remove Is `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` from your application layout?

Comment: Yeah! Accidently.
It's alright now! 
Can tell me the function of <%= csrf_meta_tags %>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you could try adding:

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:destroy]
```

Though this doesnt necessarily solve the problem as much as just gets around it.